# Recursively convert mkv to mp4 with avconv

Tags: linux, video, video-conversion

I need to create a script that can convert all .mkv files to .mp4 in a starting directory and all sub-directories under it.

I've been able to convert files one at a time by using:

```
avconv -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```

and converting all files in the current directory wouldn't be too difficult. But after hours of searching, I can't find a way to do this recursively.

I've gathered that I need to use the find command, but I'm relatively new to Linux and I get completely lost in combining find and avconv to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable recursive globbing in Bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then, a simple loop, replacing the output filename:

```
for f in **/*.mkv; do avconv -i "$f" -c copy "${f%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

Note that this may fail on videos that contain codecs MP4 containers cannot handle. MP4 is more restrictive than MKV, which can basically include all codecs.